# Updating Cells of a Child View Only

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a Collection View and showing data with NSFetchResultController in it. Then Every Cell is a tableView that show data using a different NSFetchResultController but using the same NSManageObject Context as the collectionView is using.

Now the problem is when i add a new item in a tableview the NSFetchResultController reload CollectionView cell. but i want that it should not do this. It should only update the tableView Cells.

Any idea how i can achieve this task.

[image]

Comment: What entities are handled by the FetchedResultsControllers for the collectionView and tableViews?  How are they related?  The solution will probably be in the FRC delegate methods for the collectionView - can you show that code?

Comment: the collection view cell shows types and table shows types under that type. Inshort  categories are divided over UICollectionViewCells and table view shows all items under that category

Comment: If the new items added in the tableView are part of a one-many relationship from the category in the collection view, then the collectionView FRC will probably trigger an "Update" for that cell.  One option would be to amend your delegate method to ignore "Updates".  Another option would be to create a new child context for each tableView - additions in the child context would not affect the parent (collectionView) context until saved.

Comment: but when i will save then it will call update method on collectionview too again.

Comment: True.  What about the other option - amending the FRC delegate methods to ignore updates?

Comment: will you please explain what do you meat from amending the FRC delegate methods to ignore updates?

Comment: If your collectionView is underpinned by a fetched results controller, you probably have implemented the delegate methods (which are called when the FRC is notified of any changes to the objects it fetches): `controller:didChangeSection:` and `controller:didChangeObjectAtIndexPath:`.  These methods normally update the collectionView (inserting, deleting or updating items/sections) as necessary.  If you are using these methods, you could amend them to ignore the changes that arise from changes to your tableView data.  If you post the relevant code, I (or someone) can provide a detailed answer.